# Apache HBase Replication across data centers

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, bigdata

Is this possible to have the replicated HBase region servers across data centers? 
I understand Rack Unaware and Rack Aware strategies are supported. How about Data center aware strategy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of some recent advancements it is possible. See **[this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-1295)** for more details. I would also suggest you to go through this **[pdf](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12411851/hbase_repl.3.pdf)**.

Hope this answers the question.